# Test Prices In Shopify Using Optimizely

Tags: shopify, optimizely

I'm looking to test prices in shopify using Optimizely.

I tried to change the price on the product page itself (which is just text) and increased the price by 5%. When I add the product to the shopping cart, the price of the product was still the regular price.

I realize there is probably a liquid variable which contains the price of any particular product, which I could alter in Optimizely's code editor to simply increase by 5%.

I think I can do this by using:
{{ product.price | times:1.05 | money }},

but I'm not sure how to implement in the optimizely editor, or whether this is the correct route to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As optimizely runs on the client side, this is not currently possible on shopify (if it were people would be able to change your prices in their console)

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Shopify to do with prices leads you to variants. So, in this case you could set up another variant with the different price, then have Optimizely show or hide as appropriate.